# Is it possible to use Ethiopian airlines to travel from Dublin to LAX?

Tags: air-travel, lax, dub, ethiopian-airlines, add

I remember back in 2017 booking a flight with Ethiopian airlines from Dublin to Los Angeles. The flight was surprisingly cheap (€600) for a return. Unfortunately, I no longer see the airline on flight scanning websites. I heard that the airline no longer operates the ADD-DUB-LAX route. Is this true?

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to use Ethiopian airlines to travel from Dublin to LAX?

No. https://onemileatatime.com/ethiopian-airlines-lax-houston/:

> As of summer 2019, Ethiopian Airlines will be canceling flights to Los Angeles. Ethiopian Airlines has been flying to Los Angeles since 2015, operating a flight via Dublin in both directions, where they’ve had pick-up rights.